# Intellij class symbol with gray bars

Tags: intellij-idea

Why is this class symbol different from the other two and what does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is abstract class.

[image]

All symbols list is here:

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.3/symbols-reference.html

Note that it is a new Icon in IDEA 2017, if you compare to 2016 version, it looked different:

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/symbols.html

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried to google the symbols but couldn't find them. Was afraid it was some kind of warning or error :/ (the last link doesn't work btw)

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link

Answer (score 1):

That symbol indicates an abstract class.

See [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols-reference.html);

[image]